Making the SUM clause specific to a given field
I'm trying to get a ratio of 'Good' values to the Total for a given ID.  The query below works when I only use one ID for the IN clause.  However when I add more than one ID, the Total ends up being for all IDs and not for a given ID.  Is there a way to modify the SUM to make it ID specific?  I should point out that ID is NOT a Primary Key.  They can repeat. These totals are number of records.  They are always integers.
 SELECT ID,
   COUNT (
           CASE WHEN [Status] = 'Good'
           THEN 1
           END
         ) Good,
    SUM(COUNT(*))over() as Total
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE ID IN ('ID1','ID2')
    GROUP BY ID

If for say ID1  there are 45 records.   10 of them are Status Good.   I want to return both 10 and 45 as individual values.

Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results. Also tag the RDBMS you are using.

I just edited it.  Not sure how to tell which RDBMS I'm using

You must know what database engine you are using? You must be running it somewhere? And we need to see actual data... not just a description of it.

It's SSMS 19.3.  Is that what you were asking?  I'm not sure how I can import data.  It's fairly simple based on my description isn't it?   IDs with a given status and Total IDs.

SSMS is a client interface to the RDBMS SQL Server - so please tag SQL Server

The clearer you make your question, the faster you get your answer. Most people want to see some starting raw data and then the results you wish to achieve, formatted nicely using tabular data. Of course its clear in your head, but for someone not intimately involved with your problem the clearer you can make it the better.

You probably want: SUM(COUNT(*))over(partition by ID), agree with above speaker, why not provide some sample data, not many here are mindreaders and know tsql

@siggemannen  That seems to work!   The partition by ID is exactly what I was looking for.

count(*) as Total :)

@ValNik lol, that would work too! Now, i really am curious what OP wants

@siggemannen You gave me the correct answer with the partition   That's what I wanted!

Yeah, but what if you just bin the partition and use COUNT(*)

count(*) gives you the total across all IDs.  What I wanted was a total for each ID

No it doesn't. Remove the OVER() and SUM, and just write: COUNT(*)

So that does indeed give the same result as the OVER()-SUM- partition by ID business.  I could have sworn I had tried it before!

Looks like you just want:
SELECT
  ID,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Status = 'Good' THEN 1 END) AS Good,
  COUNT(*) AS Total
FROM TABLE
WHERE ID IN ('ID1','ID2')
GROUP BY ID


Try this query and let me know if this resolve your issue
Sample Data (TABLE)
    ID  Status
    ID1 Good
    ID1 Bad
    ID1 Good
    ID2 Good
    ID2 Bad
    ID2 Bad
    ID2 Good

SELECT 
    ID, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN [Status] = 'Good' THEN 1 END) AS Good, 
    COUNT(*) AS Total, 
    SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS OverallTotal
FROM TABLE 
WHERE ID IN ('ID1', 'ID2') 
GROUP BY ID;

Output:
ID  Good    Total   OverallTotal
ID1   2       3         7
ID2   2       4         7


That's what I currently have. :)    It presents the total across all IDs as opposed to total per ID.  partition seems work.

I just updated my answer with some sample input and output @John

Generally regardless of SQL standard you'd be using - window functions will always be slower than regular aggregating functions therefore, if you don't have to - it's better to avoid them, hence for you this should do the trick:
SELECT
  ID,
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN [Status] = 'Good' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END
  ) AS good,
  COUNT(*) AS total
FROM 
  TABLE
WHERE 
  ID IN ('ID1','ID2')
GROUP BY 
  ID


That gives either 0 or 1 every single time.  Not the total per ID

@John needs a * 1.0 otherwise you get integer division

It still gives figures around 1 or 0.  It should be in the 40s for the ID I'm trying.  That's total regardless of status.  So it can never be a decimal.  Always an integer.

@John it really looked like you were after share of good. Fixed now to be separated good and total

SELECT
  ID,
  SUM(
    CASE 
      WHEN [Status] = 'Good' THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END
  ) * 1.0 / COUNT(*),
FROM 
  TABLE
WHERE 
  ID IN ('ID1','ID2')
GROUP BY 
  ID


Again that does not give the total.  It gives either 1 or 0.  The total should be in the 40s for the example I'm using.
